# Как записать в чистую следующую ячейку GoogleSpreadsheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Имеется некая таблица "А", в ней значения ячеек А2 и B2. (на рисунке 1)
[image: Рисунок 1]

Как при выполнении скрипта записать эти данные в ячейки А1 и B1 в таблицу "В" в свободное следующее поле? (на рисунке 2)

[image: Результат работы скрипта]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)):

```
var data = sheetA.getRange("A1:B1").getValues()
sheetB.appendRow(data[0])
```

Comment: Получается  sheetA, sheetB листы нынешней таблицы? Нужно чтоб в другую таблицу, а не в лист.

Comment: ReferenceError: "sheetА" is not defined.

Comment: Все работает! Тупанул. с неймом